# NSNumberFormatter to display custom labels for 10^n (10000 -> 10k)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I need to display numbers on a plot axis. The values could change but I want to avoid too long numbers that will ruin the readability of the graph.
My thought was to group every 3 characters and substitute them with K, M and so on (or a custom character).
So:
1 -> 1,
999 -> 999,
1.000 -> 1k,
1.200 -> 1.2k,
1.280 -> 1.2k,
12.800 -> 12.8k,
999.999 -> 999.9k,
1.000.000 -> 1M,
...

Note that probably I'll only need to format round numbers (1, 10, 1000, 1500, 2000, 10000, 20000, 30000, 100000, ...).
Is that possibile with NSNumberFormatter? I saw that it has a setFormat method but I don't know how much customizable it is.

I'm using NSNumberFormatter cause the graph object I use wants it to set label format and I want to avoid changing my data to set the label.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.multiplier = 0.001
formatter.positiveFormat = "#,###k"
formatter.zeroSymbol = "0"
return formatter
```

It helped me to convert the currency values:

```
2000 -> 2k
10000 -> 10k
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The closest you can get is Scientific Notation. Have a look [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Number_Format_Patterns) for how to create a format for that. You could obviously quite easily do the k, M etc substitution yourself though.

Comment: As I said the labeling method require a formatter and it is automatic based on the data so manual substitution (even if it is not smart) cannot be done.
Thanks however for the scientific notation information.